# Makeup for Mikveh on Friday Night

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Are there any sources for a leniency for a woman to wear make-up when her Mikveh night falls on a Friday considering it is [not technically a Chatziza](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chatzitza#cite_note-48)? Suppose the woman feels uncomfortable without make-up.

Comment: How do you know that make-up "is not technically a Chatziza"?

Comment: I have reworded your question to avoid it being a practical shaaleh for a Rov which would be off-topic for this site. You can edit it back if you want.

Comment: Is there not a concern that the woman may feel embarrassed at appearing in front of the mikvah lady wearing make-up?

Comment: The book Ish V'Isha says that it isn't a chatziza but that it should be removed.  I would imagine it is because it is something that she wishes to remain on her is for beauty and is only a very thin layer.

Comment: Dealing with a case where the Mikveh lady is well acquainted with the woman and knows about the issue.  alternatively there is no Mikveh lady and is using a hotel Mikveh or is on holiday using the sea.

Comment: Footnote 48 here explains further: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chatzitza#cite_note-48

Comment: excellent answers to my comments!

Comment: I heard that some are meikel to tell goy to put on makeup for them after going to the mikveh bc of shvus dshvus bimakom tzar haguf

Answer (score 4):

[Rabbi Dovid Miller](http://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/teacher.cfm/80121/rabbi-dovid-miller/), a student of R' Aharon Lichtenstein zt'l and a faculty member of YU's Gruss Kollel in Israel, has a series of four mp3s on yutorah.org on *dinai tvilah veChatzitza*. In one of those, he mentions a case of Shabbos Sheva Brachos in a Charedi culture where -- *well this isn't my world,  ... but in their world, if a woman isn't PAINTED*, people would notice. He said this woman got a *heter* to wear non-chatzitzah makeup to the Friday night Sheva Brachos and then go to the Mikvah afterwards.

(I should add in Rabbi Miller's case, not wearing makeup would essentially be broadcasting that the bride was a *Nida* during the wedding, which could be much more embarrassing than simply someone who always likes to be seen in makeup ... but that's a shade-of-gray question for a posek to address.)

So certain types of makeup, in certain circumstances, could be permissible in theory. You'd really have to consult an expert posek on those details, though.

Comment: Was she Ashkenazi?

Comment: @mevaqesh my impression was yes, Ashkenazi, Charedi, non-Hassidic.

Comment: What in the world is "non-chatzitzah makeup"?

Comment: @DannySchoemann afraid I'd have to refer you to the Rabbi Miller shiurim as I don't recall the details ... something about what sits on top of the skin vs. goes into the skin?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Maybe he meant permanent makeup. This sort of makeup R. Ovadiah Yosef permits to begin with (Taharat HaBayit vol. 3 pg. 29, num. 8).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer may be considered just a comment, but it could be an alternative solution: one may get a heter from a Rav to immerse before the onset of Shabbos in time to put on makeup before sunset and leave the mikvah's premises after nightfall.