# Mikva and makeup on yom tov

Tags: yom-tov, mikvah-ritual-bath

If a woman is due to go to the mikvah on yom tov, is there any heter to remove/add makeup on yom tov?   This is a very serious question because if a woman doesn't wear any makeup an entire yom tov, it looks suspicious among family and friends and she will be embarrassed because its obvious shes going to the mikvah. Is there any solution?

Please help. Thank you

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85311/makeup-for-mikveh-on-friday-night/85312#85312

Comment: Please reach out to your local Orthodox Rabbi for an answer for this. We can't provide practical rulings on this site, and your local Orthodox Rabbi would be the best person to help navigate this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Iggros Moshe, [Orach Chaim 1:114](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&pgnum=177) and [Orach Chaim 5:27](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&pgnum=136) rules that one is permitted to use powdered makeup that is not long lasting on Shabbos and Yom Tov.

To the best of my knowledge this is the only Heter I am aware of.